# Consulta sql fechas

Tags: sql-server

Actualmente tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT MEASURE_DT, NEXT_CHECK, USR_NAME,SQnet_Locations.DESCR,
 DOUBLE_VAL,TESTDEVICE 
FROM 
 ( (SQnet_TestValues INNER JOIN SQnet_TestDefinitions ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) 
   INNER JOIN SQnet_Users ON SQnet_TestValues.USR_CODE = SQnet_Users.REC_CODE) 
   INNER JOIN SQnet_Locations ON SQnet_TestDefinitions.PARENT_CODE = SQnet_Locations.REC_CODE 
WHERE 
 ( 
   ( (SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT) = getdate() ) 
 AND( (SQnet_TestValues.TESTDEVICE) = 4) ) 
 OR ( ( (SQnet_TestValues.TESTDEVICE) = 5) )
```

Actualmente el campo `SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT` está en formato `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

En el where estoy poniendo la condición de que los registros tienen que tener la fecha del día de la consulta. No me está filtrando bien. ¿Tengo que convertir ese campo? Y en el caso de que sea así, ¿cómo lo hago?

Un saludo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en tu where al hacer un getdate te está devolviendo también la hora exacta del momento en que ejecutas tu query, deberías castearla para que solo compare la fecha.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT MEASURE_DT, NEXT_CHECK, USR_NAME,SQnet_Locations.DESCR,  DOUBLE_VAL,TESTDEVICE  
FROM   ( (SQnet_TestValues 
INNER JOIN SQnet_TestDefinitions ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK)     
INNER JOIN SQnet_Users ON SQnet_TestValues.USR_CODE = SQnet_Users.REC_CODE)     
INNER JOIN SQnet_Locations ON SQnet_TestDefinitions.PARENT_CODE = SQnet_Locations.REC_CODE  
WHERE   (     
   ( convert(varchar, SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT, 103) = convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)  
   AND( (SQnet_TestValues.TESTDEVICE) = 4) ) 
   OR ( ( (SQnet_TestValues.TESTDEVICE) = 5) )
```